# Correct name of tool to make menus bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to make in **C# Winforms Application** the menus bar which I send the below screenshot
[image: Menu bar]

Then I'd like to add in low Winforms interface position ordered by red rectangle.
[image: Application interface]

So, I'd like to ask what kind of name of tool should I use? Any examples? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That's called a status bar (`StatusBar` or `StatusStrip` controls in WinForms).

Comment: The upper band in the first image appears a ToolStrip, with some ToolStripButtons aligned to the right. The other a MenuStrip, still with ToolStripButtons right-aligned. Or standard Buttons -- The lower band should be a StatusStrip, the StatusBar has been deprecated (in .Net Core / .Net 5+).